# is buddypress out of wordpress family?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

they removed buddypress category from their showcase, lead developer Andy Peatling is not there, and there are some sad articles on buddypress but nothing specific. Do you know what the status is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BuddyPress is still closely related to WordPress and continues to work with the platform.  Removing certain references merely helps distinguish between the two systems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your not finding the BP resources your looking for because they are in the process of renovation... as well BP has never really been that well documented. ALTHOUGH the BuddyPress crew is the process of BETA testing (version 3)... and is pretty close to launching to the world. Make no mistake BP 1.5 is going to influence Open Source Development and get alot of attention... can you tell I'm on the band wagon? I wrote on article on the good parts about BP 1.5: http://www.simondelasalle.com/articles/buddypress-1-5-the-best-parts/